# How to catch exception in groovy?

Tags: groovy, exception, jenkins-groovy

In the below code:

```
def build(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5){

    try{

        executeBuildCommand(commandString, component)
    }
    }catch(Exception e){

        print ' build() method raised exception'
        print "Error cause: ${e}"
        error('Build stage - failed')
    }
}


def executeBuildCommand(arg1, arg2){

    try{
        // BUILD_FULL = sh('build the code')

        if(BUILD_FULL == true){
            def data = new URL(${BUILD_URL}).getText()
        }        
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e
    }   
}
```

---

I understand that `"${BUILD_URL}"` interpolates in runtime

But `catch` block in `build()` method, does not catch exception thrown on line(`def data = new URL(${BUILD_URL}).getText()`)

instead I receive exception stack

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, acceptGitLabMR, 
addGitLabMRComment, addInteractivePromotion, ansiColor, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild,... ]  or 
globals [Artifactory, LastChanges, currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
```

---

How to handle exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two problems in your `executeBuildCommand`:

1. `new URL(${BUILD_URL})` means that you are trying to call some method `$` which has a closure as the only argument. You certainly wanted it to look like `new URL("${BUILD_URL}")` in order to interpolate `BUILD_URL`. Or why not use just `new URL(BUILD_URL)`?
2. As a result of point 1, you get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` for `$`. But you try to catch `Exception` which is not a superclass of `NoSuchMethodError`. The latter has `java.lang.Error` as a superclass. If you had tried catching an `Error` you'd have seen your messages

Comment: Does it make sense to raise an exception for this error? Why `catch()` in `executeBuildCommand()` does not catch the exception and propagate to parent method `build()`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You don't ever want to catch `Errors` unless you know why you're doing so. These are the class of errors usually not related to the business logic which we program. It shows you that something went wrong with your runtime. E.g. `NoSuchMethodError`(NSME) may show that, for some reason, the method you expect to exist is missing at runtime. So you should just ensure that this missing method is in place next time you run the code. `NSME` propagates but both your `catch` blocks can't catch `Error` because they are declared to catch `Exception` which is not an ancestor to `Error`

Comment: So, what is root class, to catch every error? Is it `Error`? So that I will add in catch block

Comment: It's [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Comment: My idea is to catch syntactic&runtime issues at runtime using try.....catch. Other functional issues like connection_time_out, or shell command failure, am handling by grabbing the return value. So, is this the right approach in this [context](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/214117/37254)? Your comments would be helpful to me.